# Run script on multiple files

Tags: bash, loops

I would like to execute a [script](https://github.com/ebi-pf-team/interproscan/blob/master/core/jms-implementation/support-mini-x86-32/interproscan.sh) on a batch of files all of which have .xml extension.

Inspired by previous posts, I tried the following:

```
for file in *.xml; do ./script.sh <"$file"; done
```

And

```
for i in $(\ls -d *.xml)
do
    ./script.sh -i /path/*.xml -d /output_folder $i
done
```

Both of these run the script many times but only on the first .xml file in that folder. So I end up with a dozen output files but all of them are file1.txt, file1.txt_1, file1.txt_2 etc. The loop stops randomly, sometimes after 3 iterations, sometimes after 28.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you,
TP

Comment: Do you want the script to get all the files in one shot, or do you in fact want it to run once for each xml file?  In one form you are redirecting each file into `stdin` of the script, and in another you're passing parameters, which way do you want to do it?

Comment: Understand what glob means and how to use *find* command.

Comment: The `ls -d` approach is definitely wrong, but the other one *isn't*. If `for file in *.xml; do ./script.sh <"$file"; done` **really does** iterate over all your separate xml files.

Comment: Are you sure your `script.sh` is actually paying attention to content written to it on stdin? The most obvious cause would be a case where that script isn't using what it's fed, or expects a filename on the argument list rather than file contents on stdin.

Comment: (Since the Interproscan launcher you linked just runs a Java program, reading it doesn't say anything useful about how it expects its input. That said, it *is* obviously quite buggy -- if you try to pass it an argument with whitespace, for example, expect it to be split it into two arguments).

Comment: EricRenouf : At this point I don't mind if all the files are processed simultaneously or one-by-one. The script runs with a few arguments, but they will be the same for processing each individual file. 

0andriy : thanks for the suggestions, I'm on it. 

CharlesDuffy : Sorry, I didn't realize that InterPro is just linked to a Java program and is of no use. However, none of my .xml files have whitespace. The script.sh takes arguments (like mode, path to input files and options for output), but the first generated file is valid. It just don't want to hop on the next one in the list.

Comment: @ThePresident, ...if it takes the input file as an argument, you need to pass it *as an argument*. `<"$file"` doesn't do that. `"$file"`, with no `<`, does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for f in /input_path/*.xml; do
  ./interproscan.sh -mode convert -f raw -i "$f" -d /output_path
done
```

Comment: Yup, this seems to be working. Elegant and simple as well. Thanks for your help and mostly, because I learned something :)

Answer (score 1):

More simple and safe method is this:

```
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    ./interproscan.sh -mode convert -f raw -i "$REPLY" -d /output_path
done < <(find . -iname "*.xml" -print0)
```

**NOTE**

1) Using iname you search using case insensitive.

2) "$variable" help you if filename have some space.

Comment: I will try it as well and as soon as this first test is done. Thank you!

Comment: Here, have a pathological case: `touch $'file\nname.xml'`. The only character that can't exist in a path is NUL -- newlines are on a great many common filesystems legal. Consequently, a newline-delimited stream can't be safely used to transport lists of files.

Comment: @Charles Duffy So, the only way is using a null character like i have do in my while loop.

Comment: Yup -- this is safe with all possible filenames as given. (Personally, I just use `-d ''` rather than `-d $'\0'`, since the two parse to exactly same string but `$'\0'` incorrectly implies to readers that the shell is capable of representing strings with NUL literals as contents, but that's a matter of preference/taste, not correctness.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping though the files you could use find's `-exec` option. It will execute the command on each file, replacing `{}` with the file's path. Note you must end the command with an *escaped* semicolon (`\;`).

Something like this could work for you:

`find . -name "*.xml" -exec ./script.sh -i /path/*.xml -d /output_folder {} \;`

But you are limited that you can only insert the `{}` once, alternitlvity to do it with a loop you could do this:

```
xmlFiles=( $(find . -name "*.xml") )
for i in ${xmlFiles[@]}
do
   ./script.sh -i /path/*.xml -d /output_folder $i
done
```

Comment: Same thing happens. I guess something with my script, not all your suggested methods. For the script I have to specify a single file as input argument, but instead I use *.xml, so maybe that's why it process the files all wrong

Comment: So, this is the exact way I run the script with arguments:
./interproscan.sh -mode convert -f raw -i /input_path/*.xml -d /output_path  So basically, it takes .xml files and convert them to another format called "raw" specified as argument.

Comment: `xmlFiles=( $(find . -name "*.xml") )` is quite buggy -- it'll split a file with a space in its name into two separate filenames; replace a file with a whitespace-surrounded asterisk in its name to have a list of files in the current directory; etc. If you just want files named `*.xml` in the current directory, `xmlFiles=( *.xml )` will do the job much more reliably.

Comment: For similar reasons, it should be `"${xmlFiles[@]}"` and `"$i"`. Quotes matter.